# How to get Jquery-ui Autocomplete with Codeigniter to display response text

Tags: jquery-ui, codeigniter, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have got the autocomplete to work but with errors. How would i format the response code correctly? 
**Response Code**:

```
{
    label: "Label 1",
    value: "27"
},
{
    label: "Label 2",
    value: "18"
},
{
    label: "Dave",
    value: "25"
},
{
    label: "Jacqui Potatoes",
    value: "17"
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$("#account_search .ac_input").autocomplete({ 

    minLength: 0,
    source: base_url + "accounts/ac_results/account_name",    
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",

}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
    return $( "<li></li>" );
};
```

I think the `.data()` function is the problem although it is working somehow. I would like to access both the label and value

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in the `_renderItem` function (you should call `.data` on the newly created `<li></li>`):

```
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.value + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

I also replaced `item.desc` which did not exist on your JSON response with `item.value`.

As a sidenote, you may not need to override that function at all. You only need to use it if you want to change the way each item looks in the suggestion list.

Also, make sure to remove that extra comma in the options object. Additionally, the options `dataType` and `type` are not valid options anyway:

```
$("#account_search .ac_input").autocomplete({ 
    minLength: 0,
    source: base_url + "accounts/ac_results/account_name"
});
```

**Example** (local data source): http://jsfiddle.net/nG8Q4/

Comment: When i use this code i get no results under the input, only response text in FireBug

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. if i cause an error by adding an extra `);` after your code works. I'm so confused!

Comment: If you remove the `.data("autocomplete")` portion completely, does it work?

Comment: I noticed you had an extra comma (and some invalid options) in your autocomplete initialization code. If you remove those what happens?

Comment: In your jsfiddle `item.desc` is not needed.

Comment: `dataType` and `type`. Those are valid options when making an `$.ajax` call though.

Comment: @Flukey: Thanks, updated. As I said in the answer though I'm not sure if the `_renderItem` function is needed here at all.

Comment: Can you see anything wrong with my response text? when i hard code the values like you have in the jsfiddle in it works fine but with my source it doesn't work

Comment: Do you see a response in firebug? Is it an array?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure... If it's an array it should have `[]` around it. It should look just like the response in the example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: its very odd. If i copy the response text directly from firebug and replace the source with it it works but doesn't with the url...